# Doxygen ignoring aliases

Tags: doxygen

I want to define an alias in doxygen. According to the documentation and testimonials, I just add something like this in `Doxyfile`

```
ALIASES += sideeffect="\par Side Effects:\n"
```

and then use `@sideeffect` in the source code documentation. But I get this message when running doxygen:

```
/path/to/file.f:12: warning: Found unknown command `\sideeffect'
```

I tried escaping the quotes and backslashes too:

```
ALIASES += "sideeffect=\"\\par Side Effects:\\n\""
```

and with `=` instead of `+=` (I also make sure the `ALIASES` option is not defined anywhere else in `Doxyfile`). Other options are working fine.

Even a simple `ALIASES += "foo=bar"` does not work (unknown command `\foo').

I'm using doxygen 1.7.6.1 (Ubuntu 12.04), and the `Doxyfile` created by this version has the `ALIASES` line, so I guess it should be supported. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What does happen with a more recent version of doxygen?

Comment: Does this work: `ALIASES += "foo=bar"`?

Comment: @albert I'll try to install a more recent version, but as I said in the modified question, this version created the `ALIASES` line itself. I'd like to keep the distribution if possible.

Comment: @svaberg I modified the question, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Hm. Then I don't know. I suggest creating a test project (e.g. with a single file) and generating a new, clean  `Doxyfile` using the `doxygen -g` option.

Comment: @svaberg I did that, same thing.

Comment: @albert With 1.8.6 it seems to work, but it brings new problems [with case (in)sensitivity](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/The-lowercase-problem-when-using-the-Doxygen-with-Fortran-td1243.html)

Comment: OK with version 1.8.6 the original problem is solved. The other problem is a Fortran specific problem, that has been introduced to have better links inside the Fortran code as Fortran is case insensitive, to solve this problem still a bit of work has to be done on the Fortran parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALIASES += "sideeffect = \par \"Side Effects:\" \n"
```

This worked for me:

```
\sideeffect This will cause a catastrophic explosion.
```

It yields:

[image]

I am using 1.8.3.1

Comment: No joy, sorry. It seems aliases are broken in this version.